# Running command line PHP through PHP-FPM

Tags: command-line, nginx, php

Currently I use PHP-FPM with NGINX for front end requests but also run some background processes through a long running PHP script using exec to run other scripts with the command line PHP. What I'm thinking though is that this would be more efficient if these were also run through PHP-FPM? Any ideas on how I would do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm interested for other reasons; I'd like to be able to flush the APC cache from the command line, but this uses a different cache than for the PHP-FPM processed.  If I can pipe a command to the FPM processes to execute, then the problem is solved.

Comment: @ElYobo, what about creating a new vhost - "localhost", and make some scripts available there? :) It's not a good way, but most of the people get quite quickly what you're doing.

Answer (score 9):

FPM is a tool to **M**anage **F**astCGI **P**rocesses.  Just shuffle the letters.  While it manages long-running PHP processes, it does so only under the mental umbrella of FastCGI.

Because you're creating a background work queue, you want something *designed* to manage a background work queue and running processes.

[Gearman](http://gearman.org/) is an excellent choice for the work queue half.  It's platform and language agnostic, and scan scale to the heavens and back.  The [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman) works well.

For keeping those long-running processes going, take a look at [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

The two make a great duo.  Check out [this blog post by PHP hacker Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://www.mwop.net/blog/240-Writing-Gearman-Workers-in-PHP.html) that documents some of his exploration with Gearman and Supervisor.

Comment: Link is outdated .... is it this? http://www.mwop.net/blog/240-Writing-Gearman-Workers-in-PHP.html

Comment: Indeed, that's the one.  Updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

Very late to this question (4 years) but the correct answer is `cgi-fcgi` which will let you pass commands and execute code in the already-in-memory php-fpm

Comment: Yep, I think this is what I was looking for way back then, thanks!