# how to run php -v from terminal when using php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I have Nginx installed with PHP-FPM and I cant figure out how to run php -v into terminal it says that i need to install php5-cli. How else can I run php from terminal? I am using ubuntu. I just need php from terminal to run a cron

Comment: You should install php-cli to run php from command line. Runt the command : sudo apt-get install php5-cli

Comment: would that mess with php-fpm ?

Comment: May be this one would helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314563/running-command-line-php-through-php-fpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out if the PHP installation folder is in your PATH. You can check by doing "echo $PATH". if you don't find the PHP install folder there then that's probably the problem